# Optimized SQL query for WordPress users and user meta

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

What's a more streamlined way to compose the following query?

```
SELECT
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.user_login,
wp_users.user_email,
first_name.meta_value AS first_name,
last_name.meta_value AS last_name,
status.meta_value AS status,
expiry_time.meta_value AS expiry_time,
registration_date.meta_value AS registration_date,
affiliation.meta_value AS affiliation,
phone.meta_value AS phone,
street.meta_value AS street,
city.meta_value AS city,
state.meta_value AS state,
zip.meta_value AS zip
FROM
wp_users
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS first_name ON wp_users.ID = first_name.user_id AND first_name.meta_key = 'first_name'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS last_name ON wp_users.ID = last_name.user_id AND last_name.meta_key = 'last_name'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS status ON wp_users.ID = status.user_id AND status.meta_key = 'status'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS expiry_time ON wp_users.ID = expiry_time.user_id AND expiry_time.meta_key = 'expiry_time'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS registration_date ON wp_users.ID = registration_date.user_id AND registration_date.meta_key = 'registration_date'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS affiliation ON wp_users.ID = affiliation.user_id AND affiliation.meta_key = 'affiliation'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS phone ON wp_users.ID = phone.user_id AND phone.meta_key = 'phone'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS street ON wp_users.ID = street.user_id AND street.meta_key = 'street'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS city ON wp_users.ID = city.user_id AND city.meta_key = 'city'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS state ON wp_users.ID = state.user_id AND state.meta_key = 'state'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS zip ON wp_users.ID = zip.user_id AND zip.meta_key = 'zip'
```

I know this isn't the most effective, not to mention the query runs about 60 seconds.

Comment: I think you've got the most effective way in MySQL to perform this (Chance I'm wrong as I'm not as familiar with MySQL).  Other databases have more elegant ways of processing this (crosstab or pivot in oracle), but mysql is a bit limited here.